# Google Chrome Extension Post Content of Selected Image

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webrequest, image-capture

I am working on a Chrome Extension it would post image content as bytes to my service (which is a C# web handler) and save it as a jpeg.

For example I am right clicking on StackOverflow logo and clicking on send this image to service button on the context menu. And it would post image as bytes array.

I can do it by sending image url and later on make a request to that image url and get the content, but neither I want to bother my server to make a request or hit to stackoverflow server.

It is possible?

Thanks.

Comment: That's possible. For inspiration, see [Upload a File in a Google Chrome Extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4093722/upload-a-file-in-a-google-chrome-extension/10002486#10002486) and/or [Google chrome rehost image extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11378630/google-chrome-rehost-image-extension/11382138#11382138). The image will be fetched from cache, when available.