# Javascript binary file download, and ajax file POST upload in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, ajax, file-upload, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm writing a chrome extension content script which will embed itself on some pages, and when there are certain file type links (.doc, .torrent, etc) it will download that file, and then do a file POST to a python web server which will save that file.  The python server is working, and handles a normal multipart/form-data POST request, and successfully saves the file when I use the html interface I wrote for it.

I have javascript downloading the file properly:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', 'http://foo.com/bar.torrent', false);
req.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
req.send(null);
if (req.status != 200) return '';
var response = req.responseText;
```

And then when I try to create a POST request and upload it

```
// Define a boundary, I stole this from IE but you can use any string AFAIK
var boundary = "---------------------------7da24f2e50046";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var body = '--' + boundary + '\r\n'
         // Parameter name is "file" and local filename is "temp.txt"
         + 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upfile";'
         + 'filename="temp.torrent"\r\n'
         // Add the file's mime-type
         + 'Content-type: application/bittorrent\r\n\r\n'
         + response + '\r\n';
         //+ boundary + '--';
xhr.open("POST", "http://python.server/", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader(
    "Content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary

);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
        alert("File uploaded!");
}
xhr.send(body);
```

It thinks that it uploaded successfully, but when I try to open the file it says the data is corrupted.  I think this is some kind of encoding issue, but I'm not 100% sure.

Any thoughts would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Your upload method does not work, because all binary characters are encoded as UTF-8. I posted the explanation and solution in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10073841/938089?xmlhttprequest-multipart-related-post-with-xml-and-image-as-payload) at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262266/xmlhttprequest-multipart-related-post-with-xml-and-image-as-payload).

In your case, you don't need to manually create the post data. Request the initial data in a smart way, and use the [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData) object to post the binary data. For instance:

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.onload = function() {
    // Create a form
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("upfile", x.response); // x.response is a Blob object

    // Upload to your server
    var y = new XMLHttpRequest();
    y.onload = function() {
        alert('File uploaded!');
    };
    y.open('POST', 'http://python/server/');
    y.send(fd);
};
x.responseType = 'blob';    // <-- This is necessary!
x.open('GET', 'http://foo.com/bar.torrent', true);
x.send();
```

Note: I replaced `false` with `true` at the initial request. Avoid using synchronous `XMLHttpRequest` when it's also possible to asynchronously create the request.

If you don't understand the answer, here are more examples with thorough explanations:

- [XMLHttpRequest: Multipart/Related POST with XML and image as payload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10073841/938089?xmlhttprequest-multipart-related-post-with-xml-and-image-as-payload) - `FormData` is not used, but the post data is manually created instead.
- [Upload a File in a Google Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10002486/938089?upload-a-file-in-a-google-chrome-extension) - A sample Chrome extension which uses Web Workers (with a FormData polyfill) to upload files
- [Google chrome rehost image extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11378630/google-chrome-rehost-image-extension/11382138#11382138) - Scrapes an image from the page, and upload the image to imgur using a Chrome extension.