# Is there a way to download image and upload (to another server) via javasctipt?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I would like to do some image rehosting plugin, but the target server accept only uploading from a client. No link support. In the other words, I want to download image from other server and upload to another and I need to do it from a JavaScript (browser extension ).

Comment: Yes, it is possible. what is blocking you?

Comment: @Sudarshan I don't think that its possible. Could you please share how could an image be downloaded form some URL and uploaded to other without explicit user action ?

Comment: How? Image object have no any methods to get the content.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Google chrome rehost image extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11378630/google-chrome-rehost-image-extension).

Comment: @RobW Please answer my query. Suppose i am in a cyber cafe where chrome has this extension. So viewing my friends album over "Facebook" would allow the photos to go to some server without my knowledge? Am i getting the concept right ?

Comment: @Amber Yes, but I would never log in with my main Google, Facebook or whatever important account in a Cyber cafe. You could look at `chrome://extensions/` to see if any extension is installed, but that's not a safeguard. In theory, malicious users could have installed a whatever they want in the main OS.

Comment: @Amber I suppose click in context menu to select the image, but as I see the code by Rob W link, yes, it look like it can work without user interaction.

Comment: @RobW Thanks for the information. I could have never imagine that someone could steal my photos when i am browsing over facebook. I will study this in detail.

Comment: @Amber: Why do you this is not possible? have you seen some constraints?

Comment: @Sudarshan I imagine that browser is providing security to us and it wont allow tweaking such malicious items which would send an image to some other server then. As i asked RobW, this means that surfing Facebook will give away all my photos. But now i feels its plausible and that's too scary.

Comment: "target server accept only uploading from **a client**" - what is the client? If this is not a browser, you can't do the same thing by extension, because extension is an (automated) browser, unless you craft an NPAPI plugin.

Comment: thank you Rob, extension is done!